# Что такое Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();?

Tags: java, многопоточность, стек

Что означает эта строка?

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Что такое стек, я понял. Интересует, почему мы список стеков берем из `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();`

Comment: @duddeniska Документация на этот счет дает исчерпывающий ответ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29

Answer (score 5):

Эта "Thread.getStackTrace()" строчка вызывает метод, который возвращает массив отслеживаемых элементов, которые представлены в текущем потоке. Вернет массив 0 длины, если поток не запущен или был завершен.

На верхушке будет последний из вызванных методов, в самом последнем элементе массива будет недавно запущенный метод внутри потока.

В случае ошибки обычно вызывается `getStackTrace()`, чтобы быстрее поймать баг и проследить последовательность вызова методов внутри потока. Да, к справке, его надо просматривать снизу вверх, для определения баг или чего бы то ни было. :)

Ваш вопрос "почему": так задумано, чтобы данный метод выводил массив последовательности вызова других методов.